# Clustered bar chart with clusters "normalized" so outliers are evident

Tags: data-visualization, splunk

Suppose I have a clustered bar chart and I want to find outliers in each cluster ... this is easier to explain against an example, so here it is:

[image]

Here we have counts of error codes (X axis: codes, Y axis: count) and the clusters are, say, individual machines where these errors have been logged.  You can see that `1001` is logged a bunch on all these machines, and `897` not so much.  I want to find where particular machines are outliers (high) versus the rest of the machines, for each error code cluster.

This is a pattern I could easily recognize with my eye ... but the fact that so many error `1001`s are recorded, plotted against all the other error codes, with a linear Y axis, means the differences in `897` or `176` are to small to spot.

So: Is there a way to "normalize" each cluster so that for the clusters with the small counts their counts are inflated/expanded to take up more of the Y-axis?

Comment: I think Cross Validated, http://stats.stackexchange.com/, would be better for this.

Comment: ok, I didn't realize that data visualization was part of their scope but now I see it is, thanks!

Comment: Plus, I since figured out to set the Y-axis to a log scale, and that pretty much worked.  Thing is, I'm not sure now whether to answer this with my own answer, or delete it, or what.

Comment: Funny -- I just made a blog post *against* using log scales with bars, because bars need a zero point for the length to be meaningful. http://blogs.sas.com/content/jmp/2016/06/29/graph-makeover-bars-on-a-log-scale/ More to the original question, I thought the stats folks would have a take on how to measure whether the differences are significant.

Comment: @xan That's a good post - I agree that use of log scales needs to be justified - but the case I'm looking at is "Log scales are most useful when the underlying data is very skewed or varies by many orders of magnitude".  In this case, some errors (e.g., 1001) are logged at the rate of 1000/hr and others (e.g., 309) at 10/hr (or fewer).  This is a legacy system, so the logging is what it is and the errors are what they are, and what I'm trying to find is if a new deployment - which is deployed first to one farm for a day - shows a different error _trend_: e.g., did we make it worse somehow?

Comment: ... and then we dig in to find out if it's actually a problem or not.

Comment: I can see the value for looking for things that are an order of magnitude greater. Looking at percent of total within error group may help, too.

Comment: @xan - percent of total of cluster sounds good ... I'd like to know how to get splunk to compute that ...

Answer (score 0):

you could try to first establish an average error count across all hosts, then charting the difference

```
search ...
| stats count by host error
| eventstats avg(count) as error_avg by error
| eval diff = (count-error_avg)/error_avg*100
| chart max(diff) as diff by host error
```

from there you could filter where diff is outside of a certain percentage